# Submitting my passport for student visa stamping, Must I be worried about this?

Tags: visas, damaged-passports

I have an Indian passport. There was a sticker on the back cover. Carelessly I used wet wipes to clean it out, which caused slight discoloration on the back but did not weaken the cover.

The cover is intact but, due to rubbing, 2-3 tiniest of tiniest holes occurred. That did not affect anything inside, and they are very tiny - only when I face it to direct light can I see the tiny holes.

The back of the back of cover has general information about the passport, and it is readable. Everything inside is intact and unaffected.

Should I be worried?

Comment: As ever it's impossible to say anything about "slight discolouration" and "2-3 tiny holes" which are your subjective opinion. It's better to post a photo with any details blocked out. Are the "tiny holes" the result of having something stapled to the passport?

Comment: See https://passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/online/faqLostDamagedPassports#:~:text=Duplicate%20passports%20are%20not%20issued,reason%20as%20Lost%2FDamaged%20passport.

Comment: What do you have on the other side of the page? Some countries put machine readable part in the back, some in the front. Wear passport is normal, but it should be clear there were no tampering (and not attempt to temper it). So binding (because inserting and removing pages) and pages with important information (details, photo, visas) need to be clearly not tampered. Else use your judgment. Unfortunately in this site we have both kind of people: worried of insignificant details, and people which think a washed passport without some pages are OK. So it is difficult to be objective: Ask a friend.